# How to insert one more item in a json existing structure with gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

The code below generates correctly the first structure of the json file.

```
gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

AudDetHeader AudDetHeader = new AudDetHeader();

//ArrayList<OrderDetail> AudDetList = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
Map<String, AudDet> AudDetList = new HashMap<String, AudDet>();

AudDet AudDet = new AudDet();
AudDet.setLineId("1");
AudDet.setItemNumber("ABC");
AudDet.setQuantity(9);
AudDet.setPrice(10.00);

List<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();                   
phones.add("24530001");
phones.add("24530002");
phones.add("24530003");             
AudDet.setPhones(phones);               

AudDetList.put("teste 2", AudDet);              
AudDetHeader.setAudDetList(AudDetList);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(AudDetHeader);

BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
try {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/test/test.json");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(jsonString);


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (bufferedWriter != null){
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result of the code:

```
{
  "Results": {
    "teste 2": {
      "itemNumber": "ABC",
      "lineId": "1",
      "phones": [
        "24530001",
        "24530002",
        "24530003"
      ],
      "price": 10.0,
      "quantity": 9
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add a new item. My desire is to stay as the structure below.

```
{
   "Results":{
      "teste 2":{
         "itemNumber":"ABC",
         "lineId":"1",
         "phones":[
            "24530001",
            "24530002",
            "24530003"
         ],
         "price":10.0,
         "quantity":9
      },
      "teste 3":{
         "itemNumber":"DEF",
         "lineId":"2",
         "phones":[
            "30303030",
            "40404040",
            "505050"
         ],
         "price":11.0,
         "quantity":12
      }
   }
}
```

The AudDetHeader.class

```
public class AuditoriaDetalheHeader {

@SerializedName("Results")
private Map<String, AuditoriaDetalhe> AuditoriaDetalheList;
    ...
}
```

The AudDet.class

```
public class AuditoriaDetalhe {

 String lineId = null;
 String itemNumber = null;
 int quantity = 0;
 Double price = null;
 List<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();
     ...
}
```

Comment: and the question is?  The way you have it, you should be able to create a new AudDet and then `AudDetList.put("teste 3", AudDet2);`

Comment: If I do this in code, instantiate a new class, he will write that correct structure.  `AudDetList.put (" test 3 ", AudDet);  AudDetHeader.setAudDetList (AudDetList);`  But this code is an onClick. My desire is to click on, it always create a new record in JSON.

Comment: So you want to keep the file open and continue to stream the JSON to the file as the clicks occur, appending to the list dynamically?

Comment: More or less. I can navigate the app and return to this screen, which is a form, where the fill, the data has to be inserted into existing json file.

Comment: Depending on how often your model will change, your best bet is to probably keep the model and rewrite the entire file every time the model is changed, discarding the old and replacing it with the new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me with this code!!!

**Main class**

```
private static File fileJson = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/test/test.json");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.teste_criajson);

createJsonStructure();

Button btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btSave);

btnSalvar.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            String strFileJson = getStringFromFile(fileJson.toString());            
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strFileJson);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            String idAud = "10";

            AudDet ad = new AudDet();
            ad.setLineId("2");
            ad.setItemNumber("DEF");
            ad.setQuantity(22);
            ad.setPrice(22.22);

            List<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();                   
            phones.add("22");
            phones.add("22");
            phones.add("22");               
            ad.setPhones(phones);       

            String jsonStr = jsonParser.parse(gson.toJson(ad)).toString();
            JSONObject JSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            jsonObj.getJSONObject("Results").put(idAud, JSONObject);

            writeJsonFile(fileJson, jsonObj.toString());

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

**If do not exists json file, then i create with basic structure for insert the itens.**

```
public static void createJsonStructure(){
    if(!fileJson.exists()){         
        try {
            fileJson.createNewFile();

            String jsonString = "{\"Results\":{}}";

            writeJsonFile(fileJson, jsonString);                

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Open the json file to get the string format, and prepare to insert a new item:**

```
public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    //Make sure you close all streams.
    fin.close();        
    return ret;
}
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Writes into the json file that already exists:**

```
public static void writeJsonFile(File file, String json) 
{
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(json);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null){
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```